# Add CSS classes to items on Rails index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagy

hopefully there's a simple answer to this.

```
def index

    @pagy, @drivers = pagy(
        Driver.joins(:profile).select(
          'drivers.*',
          '(profiles.no_races + profiles.no_poles + profiles.no_podiums + profiles.no_wins) AS score'
        ).reorder('score DESC'),
        page: params[:page],
        items: 16
    )

    @drivers.each do |driver|
      @subscription = driver.subscriptions.active.last

      if @subscription
        @sub_type = driver.subscription.stripe_plan
        if @sub_type == "price_xxx" || @sub_type =="price_xxx"
          @sub_type = 'gold'
        elsif @sub_type == "price_xxx" || @sub_type == "price_xxx"
          @sub_type = 'silver'
        end
      else
        @sub_type = 'free'
      end
    end
  end
```

I have a rails index page called drivers. In my controller, I select all drivers with a SQL query, which also sorts out the pagination with the @pagy gem and adds up their score.
After this I want to find out if they have a subscription and add a CSS class of gold, silver, or free depending on what sub they have in my template using `@sub_type`.

```
<div class="row mb-4">

        <% @drivers.each do |driver| %>

          <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 col-md-4 mb-3 col-lg-3 mb-3 driverCard" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <section>
              <div class="card tier <%= @sub_type %>">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="flag rounded-circle">
    .........
```

As a test, I have 32 drivers. One should be silver and one should be gold, and the rest should be free.

What actually is happening is the first page are all free, the second page are all gold and there's no silver on either page.

I'm guessing the subscriptions need to go in to the pagy query at the top of the controller? If that's the case, any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you are constantly saving over the `@sub_type` variable in your controller aren't you?  I suspect the value is always what the last item in the loop is.  I might be "better" to just create a method in a helper or somewhere and call it on each item when you loop through them.  something like `get_sub_color` and you put it in the loop `<div class="card tier <%= get_sub_color(driver.subscription.stripe_plan) %>">` and it returns the color.  That is what I would do at first thought.  That index method only gets called once when the page loads, so `@sub_type` will have the value of the last item.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought because I was looking through each driver in my controller it was updating each driver. I will give the helper method a go. Thanks!

Comment: No it doesn't work that way.  You are looping through them all, but you are also saving `@sub_type` in each loop.  So in the first loop `@sub_type` is set to silver, then it is set to gold, then set to 'free', for example.  then in the view `@sub_type` will equal 'free'.

Comment: Thanks that works nicely

Comment: @RockwellRice is it possible to order my records from the helper, i.e have all the golds together, the silvers together etc?

Comment: I would be "better" to do that somewhere else. So perhaps look into `scopes` and create a scope in the model.  Keep in mind, there are many, MANY ways to do this.  You could also just set each as its own variable using `select` on the `@drivers.subscription.stripe_plan` object in the controller, and then setting each like `@gold_drivers`, `@silver_drivers`, etc.  I think `@silver_drivers = @drivers.select { |driver| driver.subscription.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx' || driver.subscription.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'}` would work off the top of my head (could be wrong)

Comment: Thanks. What do I do if the driver doesn't have a subscription, though?

Comment: those are free, select the drivers that do not have a subscription and assign those to the `@free_driver` or whatever you want to call it.  You would likely need to check for a subscription first in your select.  There really are a lot of ways to do it.  I would read up on the `select` method and try some things out.

Comment: Ok cool. I currently have: 
`def gold_drivers
 Driver.select { |driver| driver.subscriptions > 0 && driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_1IbVo8LKPHCuCOeJC4GsXXjt' || driver.subscriptions > 0 && driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_1IcsZyLKPHCuCOeJdtyyIEny'}
    end` I have also tried scopes too, but no dice.

Comment: if you log out the value of that select what do you get?  I'm not sure there is much more I can do with the information I have so you may need to do more playing around with it or ultimately ask another question.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help @RockwellRice